# Static IP Address for Azure Cloud Service(Web Role)

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Does Azure provide a static IP address to the web role or is it dynamically allocated each time I deploy or redeploy my application ?

Comment: What are you deploying?  Website, Cloud Service or VM?

Comment: @Jason : Cloud Service

Comment: A nice explanation here... 
http://azure.codegrains.com/2013/07/azure-and-static-virtual-ip-vip.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you do not delete a deployment, but rather upgrade it, you will keep your "VIP" (Virtual IP address).

You also can deploy to a staging instance and "Swap VIP", which means moving your production VIP to your staging slot, and your staging VIP to your production slot. In effect, this moves your staging slot into production.

You cannot allocate an IP address permanently to a cloud service, however. They are permanent only within a deployment.

Comment: What do you mean by upgrade ? I usually use Visual Studio to directly publish/republish my application to azure profile. It replaces the current files, and then publishes it. Does that mean it deletes the deployment and then creates a new one ?

Comment: It depends; you'll see a Deployment Update checkbox in Visual Studio's publish. Without that option checked you are deleting the old deployment.

Comment: as pointed out by Alex in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24311361/128916), reserving IP addresses is now possible.

Answer (score 8):

Azure now supports reserving IP addresses: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/reserved-ip-addresses/

Answer (score 3):

When you deploy your cloud service, the service is assigned an IP address. You can then update the deployment in several ways without losing your assigned IP address.

Take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/10/19/announcing-improved-in-place-updates.aspx) which enumerates what you can do with in-place updates, while preserving your IP address.